# React: className to unique element in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code where I'm trying to add a `className` depending on the state of the checkbox.
So far the `className` add up nicely, but the problem is that it adds on all the elements on the list whenever I check/uncheck any checkbox.

**I want to add the classname `ClassSwitch` only when I'm checking the checkbox of it specified element on the list. How to do so ?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-moser-fmb21?file=/src/App.js:0-1009

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Eric"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Jonathan"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);

  /* Class Switch*/

  const [ClassSwitch, setClassSwitch] = React.useState("off");

  function handleClassSwitch() {
    setClassSwitch(ClassSwitch === "on" ? "off" : "on");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="select"
                  onClick={handleClassSwitch}
                />
                <span />
              </label>
              <div className={`${ClassSwitch}`}>{item.name}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to make some changes... such as this (you must keep track of check box state for each check box):

```
  .........
  const [ClassSwitch, setClassSwitch] = React.useState({});

  function handleClassSwitch(e, id) {
    setClassSwitch({
      ...ClassSwitch,
      [id]: !ClassSwitch[id]
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  value={ClassSwitch[item.id]}
                  name="select"
                  onClick={(e) => handleClassSwitch(e, item.id)}
                />
                <span />
              </label>
              <div className={`${ClassSwitch[item.id] ? "on" : "off"}`}>
                {item.name}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Or if you prefer string "on"/"off" values in state you can do that too, but you'd have to transform them to boolean when passing as value to inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed every element changes separately. But why if I check something for example as `'off'`, any next element in the list receives `'on'` ?

Comment: @AlyaKra oops my bad, check updated answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I think you missed `value` am I right ?

Comment: @AlyaKra No I missed `...ClassSwitch`.

Comment: I see. Thank you again!

Comment: One more question if it's possible. How can I put the check of the checkbox in `on` by default ? Meaning that first state is on ? Sorry for being noob I'm still new in React.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by adding `!` here `<div className={`${!ClassSwitch[item.id] ? "on" : "off"}`}>` and here `checked={ClassSwitch[item.id]}`. Is it the right way ?

Comment: @AlyaKra in that case I would just set initial value of some check box as true in the state, for example `const [ClassSwitch, setClassSwitch] =  React.useState({1:true})`

Comment: I see. Because I tried setting state to "true" and "on" and didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @gmoniava's answer, I would suggest that you keep the state of the checkbox in the object. Also a suggestion would be to use `onChange` event instead of the `onClick` for checkboxes.

Here is my version:

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);

  function handleClassSwitch(id) {
    const selectedItem = list.find(item => item.id === id);

    selectedItem.isOn = !selectedItem.isOn;
    setList([...list]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="select"
                  onChange={() => handleClassSwitch(item.id)}
                />
                <span />
              </label>
              <div className={item.isOn ? "on" : "off"}>{item.name}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't understand what you meant by "keep the state of the checkbox in the object".  Did I do something wrong in my initial code ? I'm new to React.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're handling the whole list with a single switch value, what you need is to create a different switch for every item.

in parent list component you would have something like:

```
//..code
<ul>
  { list.map(item => (
        <Item key={item.id} item={item}/>
    ))
  }
</ul>
```

your Item component may look like:

```
function Item({item}){
    const [classSwitch, setSwitch] = React.useState('off')
    
    const handleChange = e => setSwitch(classSwitch === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off')
    
    return (
       <li>
          <label>
             <input type='checkbox' onChange={handleChange} name='select' />
         </label>
         <div className={`${classSwitch}`}>{item.name}</div>
      </li>
    ) 
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I think I understood what you meant, but I think it not feasible in a loop. I see you removed `.map` so your example is working on one or multiple items without a loop. Anyway appreciate you help. I invite you to check gmoniava and Paul Cosma answers too.

Comment: you'll still have the loop, but in the parent component, what I suggested is to separate the item to handle multiple switches

Comment: Ah I see. Might aswell include it because it makes the code cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Eric"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Jonathan"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
  const [ClassSwitch, setClassSwitch] = useState({});

  function handleClassSwitch(e) {
    setClassSwitch({
      ...ClassSwitch,
      [e.target.id]: !ClassSwitch[e.target.id]
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="select"
                  id={item.id}
                  onClick={(e) => handleClassSwitch(e)}
                />
                <span />
              </label>
              <div className={`${ClassSwitch[item.id] ? "on" : "off"}`}>
                {item.name}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-morning-jdfxm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very similar to gmoniava's one.